# Show divs ease in after each other

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to display 4 divs consecutively using the ease-in css transitional feature. What i am trying to achieve I found here 
http://jsfiddle.net/57uGQ/`enter code here`but try as I might I cannot get mine which is in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/32hcm/350/`enter code here` to work accordingly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle contains no JavaScript, of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @light yes I know, i intended to separate the two so you can see the code i have written without any javascript and the other fiddle i found showing what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure. You said you tried very hard to make it work like the first fiddle. Can you show your JS code so we can point out where you have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add transition.js and you cant override opacity on multiple level. Edited opacity in #box es (removed them actually) and added the js